# How can I animate a navbar going back to the top of the website?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Right now, I have successfully animated the navbar when scrolling down on the page. However, when I go back to the top, it resets immediately, so it's not as smooth of a website as I'd like. Can anybody help me with this using Javascript? Here's what I have so far:

**JavaScript**

```
$(function () {
  $(document).scroll(function () {
      var $nav = $(".topnav");
      $nav.toggleClass('scrolled', $(this).scrollTop() > $nav.height());
    });
  $(document).scroll(function () {
      var $nav = $(".topnav");
      $nav.toggleClass('unscrolled', $(this).scrollTop() == $nav.height());
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
    .topnav.scrolled {
        background-color: #000000;
        transition: background-color 200ms linear;
    }
    .topnav.unscrolled {
        background-color: transparent;
        transition: background-color 200ms linear;
    }
```

The "unscrolled" section doesn't work, so you can ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the definition of your CSS classes, I wonder if the 'unscrolled' is added along with the 'scrolled' causing a conflict.

Can we see where you declare both `.scrolled` and `.unscrolled`?

In the meantime, not knowing anything else, I would try like so:

```
$(function () {
  $(document).scroll(function () {
      var $nav = $(".topnav");
      $nav.toggleClass('scrolled', $(this).scrollTop() > $nav.height()); // add class 'scrolled' when doc.scrollTop > nav.height, remove when not
      $nav.toggleClass('unscrolled', $(this).scrollTop() <= $nav.height()); // add scroll 'unscrolled' when doc.scrollTop <= nav.height, remove when hot
    });
});
```

Comment: I just updated my question! Thank you for helping me out.

Comment: The unscrolled still isn't working. Could it be my css?

Answer (score 0):

I usually use jQuery and have the header as fixed in the css and then this adds a class on scroll when the user has scrolled half way down the page so it is not instantly changing on scroll.

```
 $(window).scroll(function() {

    var $topNav = $(".topnav"),
        $scroll = $(window).scrollTop(),
        $wh = window.innerHeight / 2;

    if ($scroll > $wh) {
        $topNav.addClass("scrolled");
    } else {
        $topNav.removeClass("scrolled");
    }

});
```

You can change $wh to whatever you want, number or pixels from top etc...

Comment: Will this reanimate to the original topnav color when I scroll back to the top? If not, how can I do that?

Comment: Yes, you don’t need to add 2 classes, just style the .topnav the way it should look and then style .scroll how you want it to look when the class is added. 

The transition style should be in the .topnav only and not on the .scroll tag. You want the topnav to always animate so don’t remove and try to add it again.